# My turtle background does not appear on screen and I get an error

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

Hi I’ve been doing som turtle programming on python 3(newest version) and I’ve run into a problem. I can’t get the background img to load! Here is my code:

```
import turtle
wn = turtle.Screen()
Wn.title(‘space invaders’)
Wn.bgpic(background.jpg)
```

Ignoring the capital vs lowercase w in there, what is wrong with this? My background doesn’t come up and it has an error saying it’s unable to read file contents. Pls help me. (P.S I’ve tried .png and .gif)

Comment: Try a fully-qualified path for your background image, like `C:\Images\background.jpg`

Answer (score 2):

A little test, and reading the help:

```
>>> import turtle
>>> s=turtle.Screen()
>>> s.title('space invaders')
>>> help(s.bgpic)
Help on method bgpic in module turtle:

bgpic(self, picname=None) method of turtle._Screen instance
    Set background image or return name of current backgroundimage.

    Optional argument:
    picname -- a string, name of a gif-file or "nopic".

    If picname is a filename, set the corresponding image as background.
    If picname is "nopic", delete backgroundimage, if present.
    If picname is None, return the filename of the current backgroundimage.

    Example (for a TurtleScreen instance named screen):
    >>> screen.bgpic()
    'nopic'
    >>> screen.bgpic("landscape.gif")
    >>> screen.bgpic()
    'landscape.gif'
```

Looks like it needs to be a gif:

```
>>> s.bgpic('test.gif')
>>>
```

That worked for me.  Try another .gif file since you said you tried one already.  Maybe it really was corrupt.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation you should pass the string which is a filename of file that you want to use as background.

Documentation also states that you can use GIFs. PNG will do too. JPEGs don't work with turtle.

`wn.bgpic("background.png")` or 
`wn.bgpic("background.gif")`

Perhaps your files are corrupt.

(Note, changing file extension of file doesn't actually change it's type)